How to ensure useEffect cleanup is only called on unmount instead of on mount and unmount with React Strict Mode on?
React Strict Mode forces useEffects to double render. The problem is that this causes the cleanup code to run on page enter AND exit. Instead of just on exit like the cleanup should do.
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        console.log('do you only call once?')
        // TODO: Fix why this is resetting to init state when I ENTER instead of just leave
        // dispatch(resetToInitialState())
    }
}, [])

The above code will trigger once when entering the page, another time when exiting. The issue is that I'd set states before navigating in the page, and the React Strict mode would mean the cleanup resets everything to initial state...
Is there anyway to prevent cleanup from being called on page enter without disabling React Strict mode? Note that I fixed it by disabling React Strict mode, but wanted to keep it on if possible.

Sounds like Strict Mode is doing its job and exposing issues with your component rendering. See https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development

I don't think this can be fixed. This is the native useEffect behavior with Strict Mode, described in the documentation.
https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode
Your components will re-run Effects an extra time to find bugs caused by missing Effect cleanup.


Be sure that the clean up code of useEffect hook will fire only on unmount event of a component. It will never run on mounting a component.
Please check the logs below create by the following sample code.
Please note that there "Unmounted" has always been logged after "Mounted". There is no "Unmounted" logged repeatedly.
If your observation was right, then there should have been repeated "Unmounted" logs created. It does not happen.
App.js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      {!someState && <TestComponent />}
      {someState && <TestComponent />}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setSomeState(!someState)}>
        Toggle Mount/Unmount
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

function TestComponent() {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Mounted');
    return () => {
      console.log('Unmounted');
    };
  }, []);
}

Console logs
The below three logs created on the initial render
// Mounted
// Unmounted
// Mounted

The below four logs created on clicking the button once
// Unmounted
// Mounted
// Unmounted
// Mounted

The below four logs created on clicking the button a second time
// Unmounted
// Mounted
// Unmounted
// Mounted

